# Bit size of GLib types and portability to more exotic (think 16 bit char) platforms

Tags: c++, c, portability, glib

For example, given the definition at https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html:

> **gint8**
>
> `typedef signed char gint8;`
>
> A signed integer guaranteed to be 8 bits on all platforms. Values of
>   this type can range from G_MININT8 (= -128) to G_MAXINT8 (= 127)

-- what does GLIb do to guarantee the type still being 8 bits on platforms where char is not 8 bits? Or is GLib x86 / etc. only (i.e. is this a known limitation)?

Comment: The number of platforms where `char` is *not* 8 bits but still in use today can probably be counted easily using only one hand. But you should probably look for more context, like `#ifdef` surrounding the definitions.

Comment: It simply does it by not supporting such a platform.

Comment: if such a platform would still exist and be worth supporting glib would most likely just rely on the compiler to provide a 8 bit type that it translates appropriately for the platform. Somewhat similar to how 64 bit integers work on 32 bit cpus.

Comment: Indeed, just stumbled on "Pointers are always at least 32 bits in size (on all platforms GLib intends to support). Thus you can store at least 32-bit integer values in a pointer value." while reading the docs further.

Comment: Prefer those aliases defined on `<cstdint>/<stdint.h>` to library specific. That are standard defined, which makes them more dependable, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans Passant said in his comment, glib guarantees that `gint8` is 8-bits by not supporting platforms where `signed char` is any other size. There are only two types of systems that have ever had C compiler implemenations where this requirement wasn't met.

The first is systems where the byte size is 9-bits. Today these are long obsolete, but systems like these had some of the earliest C compilers. It theory it could be possible for the compiler to emulate a restricted range 8-bit type as an extension, but it would still be 9-bits long in memory, and not really get you anything.

The second are word addressable systems, were the word size is either 16, 32 or 64 bits. In these computers the processor can only address memory at word boundaries. Address 0 is the first word, address 1 is the second word, and so on without any overlap between words. For the most part systems like these are obsolete now, but not anywhere as much as 9-bit byte machines. There's apparently still at least some use of word addressable processors in embedded systems.

In C compilers targeting word addressable systems the size of a byte is either the word size or 8 bits depending on the compiler. Some compilers gave a choice. Having word size bytes is the simple way to go. Implementing 8-bit bytes on other hand requires a fair bit of work. Not only does the compiler have to use multiple instructions to access the separate 8-bit values contained in each word, it also had to emulate a byte addressable pointer. This usually means `char` pointers have a different size than `int` pointers, as byte addressable pointers need more room to store both the address and a byte offset.

Needless to say the compilers that use word sized bytes wouldn't be supported by glib, while the ones using 8-bit bytes would at least be able implement `gint8`. Though they still probably wouldn't be supported for a number of other reasons. The fact that `sizeof(char *) > size(int *)` is true might be a problem.

I should also point out that there a few other long obsolete systems that, while having C compilers that used an 8-bit byte, still didn't have a type that meets the requirements of `gint8`. These are the systems that used ones' complement or signed magnitude integers, meaning that `signed char` ranged from -127 to 127 instead of the -128 to 127 range guaranteed by glib.

Answer (score 2):

`gint8` (together with other platform dependent types) is declared in `glibconfig.h`, usually installed under `/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include`.

That file is generate at [configure time](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/Makefile.am?id=2.40.0#n5) so, at least theoretically, `gint8` can be something different.